# how to make a fixed position on tabs when i have more than 4 tabs

Tags: android, android-viewpager, material-design, android-tablayout

when i read a docs on ***material.io*** about fixed tab, i don't know how to implemented fixed tabs if i have 9 tabs in tabslayout. N -> 9 means that i have 9 tabs in ***tabslayout***. but, when i clicked a tab and access a viewpager page 7. how i can make tab still on position 7 on tab layout?

[image]